# Laravel: using "morphMany" and joining another table?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel too. I have a question about Eloquent:

**table structures:**

```
User: id, username

Posts: id, user_id, content

Likes: id, likeable_type, likeable_id, user_id
```

(Because of I want to make 'Likes' table extendable for comments, too.)

**Models\Likes.php**

```
class Likes extends Model

public function likeable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Models\Post.php**

```
class Posts extends Model

public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphMany("\App\Models\Likes","likeable");
}
```

And when I call

```
$post = Posts::find($id)->likes()->get();
```

in my controllers, it will return like this:

```
"likes": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "likeable_type": "App\\Models\\Posts",
  "likeable_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "likeable_type": "App\\Models\\Posts",
  "likeable_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
}]
```

But how can I get results like this:

```
"likes": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "likeable_type": "App\\Models\\Posts",
  "likeable_id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "username":"chenhui",//join user on user.id = likes.user_id
}...
```

Many thanks and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Do you have a relationship on your Likes model pointing to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your Likes model you need

```
class Likes extends Model

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

and then it should be:

```
$post = Posts::find($id)->likes()->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! It returns an error: 'Method with does not exist.', but you inspire me to add `protected $with = 'user';` to Likes model, and it solved my problem!!!

Comment: Glad to hear i could help!